# Evaluate all pairs of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a function `f` which takes 2 matrices with the same number of rows and procudes a scalar value. A am now looking for a possibility to create a new function which takes two lists of matrices and calls `f` for all pairs.

I need a moore efficient implementation of this loop:

```
% X = cell of matrices
% Y = cell of matrices
for k=1:length(X)
    for l=1:length(Y)
        M(k,l) = f(X{k},Y{l});
    end
end
```

(It is not a requirement that X and Y are cells)

For example `f` could be the mean of squared distances

```
f = @(X,Y) mean(mean(bsxfun(@plus,dot(X,X,1)',dot(Y,Y,1))-2*(X'*Y)));
```

but don't question `f`, it is just an example of a much more complicated problem.

Comment: questioning `f` is probably the most important way to improve efficiency. If `f` takes two n-by-m matrices and produces a scalar that's one thing, but it it can be written so that it can take two n-by-m-by-2 matrices and produce a 2 element vector, that's probably your best option.

Comment: Adding few more things to @Dan's question, though these are purely my views - Maybe you could share one of those functions that you would be using. You said it's complicated, so that could also form a new question.

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately the functions f (there are many) are not under my control. I just can to wrap them in a new function as described above.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt Have you tested to see if these functions are vectorized? Perhaps they already are...

Comment: As long as you can't change the operation of the function `f` itself, there is no way around calling this function for each pair of matrices. I think whatever tricks you use, the time gain will be minimal. Except, maybe, using parallelization; see `parfor`.

Comment: @A.Donda I strongly disagree, pre-allocating memory for the output matrix can make a very large difference to speed efficiency of loops in Matlab. `parfor` is a great suggestion though.

Comment: @Dan, you are right, pre-allocation will help, even possibly a lot. I just meant that there's no way to vectorize a function call without the function itself being vectorized.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you should be pre-allocating `M`. Then you can cut out one loop quite easily by using `meshgrid` to generate a list of all pairs of elements in X and Y:

```
[K, L] = meshgrid(1:length(X), 1:length(Y));

M = zeros(size(K));  %//This preallocation alone should give you a significant speed up
for ii = 1:numel(K)
    M(ii) = f(X{K(ii)},Y{L(ii)});
end
```

However, if you can implement `f` so that it is properly vectorized, you might be able to pass it two 3D matrices, i.e. the entire list of X and Y pairs and do it without a loop at all. But this depends entirely on what it is that your `f` does.

Comment: Are you sure that transforming two for loops into one at the cost of generating two (possibly large) matrices increases speed?

Comment: No. As I already mentioned (albeit in a comment to the other answer) the only way you can tell if a method is speed efficient in Matlab is by testing it using `timeit` or even just `tic` and `toc`. But also the OP could probably even get a speed up by just switching the two loops so that they work down the columns as that is how Matlab assigns matrices. However I do think that pre-allocating memory will make the biggest difference at all at pretty much no cost.

Answer (score 0):

On possible solution that works is using cellfun

```
fy   = @(x,Y) cellfun(@(y) f(x,y), Y);
fx   = @(X,Y) cellfun(@(x) fy(x,Y), X, 'UniformOutput', false);
newF = @(X,Y) cell2mat(fx(X,Y)')';
```

however I suppose there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you done a time test comparing this method to your two loop method and my pre-allocation + one loop method? I suggest you do it either using the `timeit` function (available on the file exchange if you don't have 2013b) or simply with loops and `tic` and `tic`. That's the only way for you to know which method is the most efficient.