# Apply function on pair of matrices from two 4-D matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a function that takes two arrays and returns a scalar called `mad`, I have two matrices 4-D in which `M(:,:,i,j)` represent a block in a block matrix, I want to apply `mad` on every combination of `M1(:,:,i,j)` and `M2(:,:,k,l)`, let's explain further, I want code equivalent to this:

```
arrayfun(@(i,j,k,l) mad(M1(:,:,i,j),M2(:,:,k,l)),1:size(M1,1),1:size(M1,2),1:size(M2,1),1:size(M2,2));
```

`arrayfun` will work but it's slow, even slower than `for-loop` in MATLAB, I want vector code not for-loop.

I'm beginner to matlab, I know `bsxfun` but this function work with functions that takes two arguments only , though mad has only two arguments, apparently `@(i,j,k,l)` has four.

There is a question that's exactly my one which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362882/evaluate-all-pairs-of-matrices) but the answers won't work as the OP has cell matrices, I have managed to obtain 4-D matrices(aka matrix of matrices) so I think I must have a better solution than meshgrid, meshgrid won't work for me as my data are going to be big(image data to be more specific).

One last thing, I thought of using a syntax like this:

```
bsxfun(@(i,j) mad(M1(i(1),1(2)),M2(j(1),j(2))),[1:size(M1,1) 1:size(M1,2)],[1:size(M2,1) 1:size(M2,2)]);
```

tried it , didn't work, I got

> Index A(I) 2 out of bound 1.

So what to do ?

### PS

`M1(:,:,i,j)` and `M2(:,:,k,l)` is of equal size for all `i,j,k,l` (aka `size(M1(:,:,i,j))==size(M2(:,:,k,l))` but `size(M1)` need not equal `size(M2)`)

### EDIT

`mad` function is only doing `sum(sum(abs(M1-M2)))/numel(M1)`.

Comment: The only way to make this faster is to optimize the `mad` function itself. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: Just to clarify, shouldn't it be `1:size(M1,3)`,`1:size(M1,4)`, `1:size(M2,3)`, `1:size(M2,4)`? Also `bsxfun` wont work similar to `arrayfun`.  Using `1:size(M1,3)`, `1:size(M1,4)` etc inside `arrayfun` will iterate both at same time.. are you sure you want to do that? or do you want to compare each 2D slice with every other 2D slice of other 4D matrix?

Comment: @SanthanSalai I want to compare each 2D slice with every other 2D slice of the other 4D matrix

Comment: @niceman, could you give a rough estimate of the size of your 2 matrices?

Comment: @SanthanSalai 16*16, the 4D matrices will have around 50*50 2D slice

Comment: @niceman, Dimensions of both matrix in this format please. `mxnxkxl`

Comment: @SanthanSalai sorry but it's really hard to explain when 4D, it's `50*50*16*16`

Comment: both M1 and M2 have same dimensions right? You could use `size(M1)` to get the correct dimensions in correct order

Answer (score 0):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/permute.html)

```
out1 = bsxfun(@minus, M1, permute(M2,[1 2 5 6 3 4]));

out = squeeze(sum(sum(abs(out1)))/numel(M1(:,:,1,1)));
```

> The result obtained should be a 4D matrix. Where each 2D slice of the `out` matrix is obtained by comparing a 2D slice of `M2` with every 2D slice of the `M1`(4D matrix). Column length of `out` should be equal to the size of 3rd dimension of `M1`. Row length should be equal to the size of 4th dimension of `M1`. Size of the 3rd and 4th dimension of your `out` matrix will be equal to the size of 3rd and 4th dimension of your `M2` matrix respectively.

I suggest you try it for a very simple example and verify the results before carrying it out for your actual dimensions.